# The Tun state of a tardigrade

Tags: zoology, ethology

I was wondering How long does it take for a tardigrade to enter and exit the Tun state?

I'm doing a thesis on tardigrades for my B.S in biology and I haven't come along any information in the primary literature talking about how long roughly, it takes to *enter* the tun state in cryptobiosis. I understand that it takes a couple hours for it to pop back up again, but what about entering?